# Is a focal point anywhere within a plane mirror?

Tags: reflection

I know that an image on a plane mirror is always upright and the same size, but is there any focal point?  Could there actually be no focal point because of that?

Comment: You can imagine a planar mirror as part of a circular mirror whose radius of curvature, r, is at infinity. Because the focal point of such mirror will be at r/2, then for  a flat mirror the focal point will be at infinity. Also, because of this any image will be formed at the same position than the original object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A focal 'point' implies a convergence of light rays to some point in space whether it be a real or virtual point. And convergence of either transmissive or reflective optics requires curvature in the optics - so for plane mirrors, no there is no focal point that can occur by reflected light.